# SQL Query not returning expected results from UNION

Tags: sql-server

I’ve got several SQL Server 2008R2 queries that are the basis for some Telerik sub-reports. I have to account:
     1. for the possibility of the EncounterCode in tblVentilatorGeneralSetup being NULL as it’s a new field hence the CASE and COALESCE statements
     2. the ModifyDate always being greater than the VisitDate in tblScheduleData
     3. having the most recent entries for both Primary and where shown in the table Secondary Settings, hence the UNION and the MAX statements.
The Problem is I’m only seeing one value, the most recent visit in the results, where there should be a result for both the Primary and Secondary Settings.

I’ve tried several variations, restructuring the queries,  running each side of the UNION separately, but nothing works.

```
 DECLARE @CaseNum nvarchar (15)= '25189001'
 DECLARE @Enc int =  '10664'

    SELECT TOP 1 v.VentilatorType + ' (' + v.Ventilator + ')' AS Vent,         v.Ventilator, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, 
v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow,     v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation,
    v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, s.VisitDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN v.EncounterCode IS NULL THEN s.Encounter_code  
            ELSE v.EncounterCode
        END AS EncounterCode
FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup v
INNER JOIN tblScheduleData s ON s.CaseNumber = v.CaseNumber
WHERE v.CaseNumber = @CaseNum AND @Enc = COALESCE(v.EncounterCode, s.Encounter_code) AND v.Ventilator = 'Primary Settings'
AND v.ModifyDate = (SELECT MAX(ModifyDate) FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup WHERE CaseNumber = @CaseNum)
AND v.ModifyDate >= s.VisitDate
UNION 
SELECT TOP 1 v.VentilatorType + ' (' + v.Ventilator + ')' AS Vent,  v.Ventilator, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, 
v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow, v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation,
v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, s.VisitDate,
     CASE 
        WHEN v.EncounterCode IS NULL THEN s.Encounter_code  
            ELSE v.EncounterCode
        END AS EncounterCode
FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup v
INNER JOIN tblScheduleData s ON s.CaseNumber = v.CaseNumber
WHERE v.CaseNumber = @CaseNum AND @Enc = COALESCE(v.EncounterCode, s.Encounter_code) AND v.Ventilator = 'Secondary Settings'
AND v.ModifyDate = (SELECT MAX(ModifyDate) FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup WHERE CaseNumber = @CaseNum)
AND v.ModifyDate >= s.VisitDate
    ORDER BY  v.Ventilator
```

I should see two rows, The Primary and Secondary settings, but I'm just seeing one row.

Comment: Are you seeing the result for `v.Ventilator = 'Primary Settings'` or are you seeing the result for `v.Ventilator = 'Secondary Settings'`? Also, I can't see an `ORDER BY` for the first part before the `UNION`.

Comment: Depends on which is most recent, Primary or Secondary. I could only ORDER the first part of the UNION by using a sub-query in the FROM section.

Comment: Can you share table generate scripts and sample data insert scripts ?

Comment: You got a lot going on here that's hard to decipher. Have you tried UNION ALL? UNION returns a unique result set, thus removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to remove the SELECT(MAX):

(SELECT MAX(ModifyDate) FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup WHERE CaseNumber = @CaseNum)
AND v.ModifyDate >= s.VisitDate
    ORDER BY  v.Ventilator

And to put the FROM into a sub-query:

```
DECLARE @CaseNum nvarchar (15)= '26616001'
DECLARE @Enc int =  '11057'

SELECT v.VentilatorType + ' (' + v.Ventilator + ')' AS Vent, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow, v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, v.VisitDate
**FROM (SELECT TOP 1 v.VentilatorType, v.Ventilator, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow, v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, s.VisitDate**
FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup v
INNER JOIN tblScheduleData s ON s.CaseNumber = v.CaseNumber
WHERE v.CaseNumber = @CaseNum AND @Enc = COALESCE(v.EncounterCode, s.Encounter_code) AND v.Ventilator = 'Primary Settings'
AND v.ModifyDate >= s.VisitDate
ORDER BY v.Ventilator) v
UNION
SELECT v.VentilatorType + ' (' + v.Ventilator + ')' AS Vent, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow, v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, v.VisitDate
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 v.VentilatorType, v.Ventilator, v.VentilatorMode,  v.Prescribed_RespiratoryRate, v.Prescribed_MinuteVentilation, v.Prescribed_Map, v.Prescribed_PeakFlow, v.Prescribed_IERatio, v.CaseNumber, v.EncounterCode, v.ModifyDate, s.VisitDate
FROM tblVentilatorGeneralSetup v
INNER JOIN tblScheduleData s ON s.CaseNumber = v.CaseNumber
WHERE v.CaseNumber = @CaseNum AND @Enc = COALESCE(v.EncounterCode, s.Encounter_code) AND v.Ventilator = 'Secondary Settings'
AND v.ModifyDate >= s.VisitDate
ORDER BY v.Ventilator) v
```

Thank you for all the suggestions.

JackW9653